# How to fill up an UIImageView by another image?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I would like to fill up an empty UIImageView by another Image.However the two pictures have not the same width, Height and shapes.So what I should do is to scale the second image until it fills up all the area and it should be displayed only there.My problem is how should I proceed.For this moment I can only put the image into the empty area without filling it up.Any idea please ?

Comment: `imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill; imgView.image = newImage; [imgView sizeToFit];`

Comment: (If I remember correctly; haven't done iOS stuff in a while.)

Comment: Yes I try this one..But here the contour of the first image is not showing no more..and Even I can't drag and drop the second image into the UIImageView.

Answer (score 5):

1. please set clipsToBound=YES

   ```
   UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
   img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimage"];
   img.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
   img.clipsToBounds = YES;
   ```

Answer (score 4):

Simply set the content mode to UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill, as H2CO3 suggested. Try this.

```
yourImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
img.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
```

This can solve your problem.